# Чем меньше расстояние, тем больше переменная

Tags: unity3d, зависимости

Прошу, напишите код, буду благодарен, мучаюсь уже 2 дня, не получается, точнее не работает, нужен вот чистый ваш код, он не большой будет.

Вот мой код:

Результата 0

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Atf : MonoBehaviour {
public Transform target;
public float adrd;
public float adrw;
        void Update ()
    {
        adrd = Vector3.Distance(transform.position,target.position);
        if (adrd<30) { 
        adrw +=1
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первое что пришло в голову это ввести константу при минимальном расстоянии.

```
float max = 1000;
```

Тогда формула выглядела бы так:

```
    adrd = Vector3.Distance(transform.position,target.position);
    adrw = max - adrd;
```

Answer (score 0):

Инициализируем переменную-член для первоначальной дистанции (например в конструкторе):

```
//где-то в конструкции или функции init() (и т.п., там, где становитися известно первоначальное растояние между объектами)
init_adrd = Vector3.Distance(transform.position,target.position);
```

в методе Update() вычисляем:

```
adrd = Vector3.Distance(transform.position,target.position);
adrw = init_adrd - adrd;
```